# Using a voltage divider and an N-channel MOSFET to switch an Arduino input pin from a EL2008 Beckhoff digital output module

Tags: mosfet, voltage-divider, level-shifting

I need to switch an Arduino input pin (0-5 V, max current is 40 mA) from an EL2008 Beckhoff digital output module (+24 V HIGH, 0V LOW, max output current of 0.5 A) using the circuit depicted below. I have not tested the circuit outside of simulations.

Would it work as desired?

That is, if I connect the source to the Arduino's pin would it

1. Switch the pin
2. Not damage the Arduino
3. Will the resistors burn up from the power being dissipated?

Please note: I am using Vcc from the Arduino as the drain-to-source voltage. Additionally, I've used a battery of 24 V and 48 ohm internal resistance to mimic the HIGH state (@ 0.5 A) of the EL2008 Beckhoff module.

- N-Channel MOSFET: IRL520N
- Resistors: 1.5K Ohm and 390 Ohm (both 1/4 W)

[image]

Comment: It won't work. As it is connected now, `P23` is always connected to `GND`. If you use the nMOSFET you need to change `D1` into a resistor and connect the `drain` to `P23`. Or use a pMOSFET, get rid of the diode and connect a resistor between `source` and `GND`. Connect `P23` to the source.

Comment: Should D23 be above the MOSFET?

Comment: As for the power dissipated: `P = UI = U * U / R` so that's `0.3W`. I'd use resistors of an order x1000 bigger.

Comment: Depends on the mosfet. Trace your line now, it goes directly to the negative pole of the your 24V source.

Comment: I'm using an N-channel, therefore current travels into drain and out of source, correct? If I put the Vout of the D23 pin above the MOSFET, it should travel into the pin, correct?

Comment: Yes from Vcc to P23. As a rule of thumb, if you use a n-channel you place the mosfet on the lowside, if you use a p-channel you place the mosfet on the highside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you need to use a mosfet? Why not just use an optocoupler:

[image]

But if you need to use the mosfet, keep the common 0V reference:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Could I ask, why have you got a 51K ohm resistor, specifically?

Comment: @GRANDMAST3R5 For the PC817 you can use values as low as a few hundred ohms. Typical internal pull-ups in micro-controllers normally go from 10k to 150k. In both circuits above you can even disregard the pull-up resistors if the digital input can be configured with an internal one.

Comment: upvote for recommending an optocoupler.